# How to find the english translation of my local language sp website?

Tags: 2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 online website in the dutch language. I dont want to change the default language!. I sometimes following SharePoint tutorials in english language. It is sometimes difficult to follow this tutorial. Is it possible to open some resource file or something else to find the translation from english to dutch or visa versa?

ps. I dont want to use some translation website like google translation. I need to know the original sp translation.

Comment: Try changing the priority language in your browser to English and refresh/close-open your browser, then the language should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the priority language in your browser to English and refresh/close-open your browser, then the language should be updated.

Comment: So the language of sp 2013 online is dependance the default language of the browser?